# Regex for date and 3-letter code

Tags: regex

been trying to create a REGEX that will parse date and 3-letter code from a bit longer message. Here I will post examples of the messages and what I want to get:

```
AAA BBB 1A BY PEK14JUN18/1654 OR QQQ MF 812 XXXXX -> PEK, 14JUN18/1654
XXX/WWWW BY 05JUL 0900 BKK LT ELSE BKG WILL BE QQQQ -> BKK, 05JUL 0900
TO AZ BY 02AUG 1910 TYO OR AZ WWWW WILL BE XXX -> TYO, 02AUG 1910
BY TYO20JUL18/0355 OR CXL CA ALL QQQ -> TYO, 20JUL18/0355
BY AMS04JUL18/1954 OR CXL MF 812 L07JUL -> AMS, 04JUL18/1954
```

I want to be able to match 3-letter code and the date for every message. The code is always nearby the date but can be before or after the date part. Also the date part can be with or without a year.Is it possible to have one regex to use for all the above examples?

I started with this:

```
(\s[A-Z]{3}\d\d|\d\d[A-Z]{3}\s)
```

(https://regex101.com/r/LPLjgf/1) but it's not working as it should and I'm not very experienced with regex to be honest.

**EDIT:**

Actually I would need to use only the 3-letter codes but I need them to be connected with a date - for example in:

```
AAA BBB 1A BY PEK14JUN18/1654 OR QQQ MF 812 XXXXX
```

the `AAA, BBB or QQQ` shouldn't match because they arent right after / before the date as is `PEK`.
Same with BY `TYO20JUL18/0355 OR CXL CA ALL QQQ` -> only `TYO` should match because it's before a date and `CXL` shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
([A-Z]{3})(\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2}\/\d{4})|(\d{2}[A-Z]{3} \d{4}) ([A-Z]{3})
```

- `([A-Z]{3})` Capturing group for three capital letters
- `(\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2}\/\d{4})` Capturing group for two digits, three upper case letters, two digits, `/`, four digits.
- `|` Logical OR, alternates pattern.
- `(\d{2}[A-Z]{3} \d{4})` Capturing group. Captures two digits, three upper case letters, whitespace and four digits.
- `([A-Z]{3})` Capturing group for three upper case letters.

You can try it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/HXOXeR/2).

---

Captured groups:

```
Group 1.    14-17   `PEK`
Group 2.    17-29   `14JUN18/1654`

Group 3.    83-93   `05JUL 0900`
Group 4.    94-97   `BKK`

Group 3.    151-161 `02AUG 1910`
Group 4.    162-165 `TYO`

Group 1.    211-214 `TYO`
Group 2.    214-226 `20JUL18/0355`

Group 1.    269-272 `AMS`
Group 2.    272-284 `04JUL18/1954`

Group 1.    342-345 `PEK`
Group 2.    345-357 `14JUN18/1654`

Group 1.    378-381 `TYO`
Group 2.    381-393 `20JUL18/0355`
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

> ```
> (\s[A-Z]{3}\d\d|\d\d[A-Z]{3}\s)
> ```

The alternation – `|` – means that will match `\s[A-Z]{3}\d\d` *or* `\d\d[A-Z]{3}\s` which is certainly not what you want. To narrow the scope of an alternation use grouping.

I would think you want to match this fairly directly:

```
([A-Z]{3})\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2}
```

And that only captures the three letters in a group.

Comment: That's a good one but it doesn't catch the 3rd and 4th option.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following RegEx:

```
[A-Z]{3}(\d{2}[A-Z]{3}[\S]*)|(\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\s\d{4}\s[A-Z]{3})
```

It will matach 3 letters fowed by 2 numbers, followed by 3 letters OR 2 numbers followed by 3 letters, a Space, 4 numbers, a Space and 3 letters.
You can try it [here](http://bak-o-soft.dk/RegEx/RegExBuilder.aspx)